# Prioritize multiple regex patterns

Tags: python

I want to try a second pattern only if the first one didn't match. The use of the `Match` object is the same in both cases. Is there any way to make it shorter?

```
for line in cli.splitlines():
    res = re.search('\s*(.*) (.*);', line)
    if res:
        pairs_found[res.groups()[0]] = res.groups()[1]
    else:
        res = re.search('(\w*) (\d*) {', line)
        if res:
            pairs_found[res.groups()[0]] = res.groups()[1]
```

Comment: I have a feeling you meant `pairs_found[res.groups()[1]] = res.groups()[2]` (group `0` is always the full match) which can also simply be `pairs_found[res.groups(1)] = res.groups(2)` or even `pairs_found[res[1]] = res[2]`

Comment: you are right, i have made the correction. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following precompiles the regexes into patterns and uses the behaviour of `or` to evaluate to the first match:

```
pat1 = re.compile('\s*(.*) (.*);')
pat2 = re.compile('(\w*) (\d*) {')

# or forced into one line:
# pat1, pat2 = map(re.compile, ['\s*(.*) (.*);', '(\w*) (\d*) {'])

for line in cli.splitlines():
    res = pat1.search(line) or pat2.search(line)
    if res:
        pairs_found[res.groups()[0]] = res.groups()[1]
```

In Python >= 3.8, you can use an assignment expression to shorten it even more:

```
    if res := (pat1.search(line) or pat2.search(line)):
        pairs_found[res.groups()[0]] = res.groups()[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

```
for line in cli.splitlines():
    res = re.search('\s*(.*) (.*);', line)
    if not res: res = re.search('(\w*) (\d*) {', line)
    if res: pairs_found[res.groups()[0]] = res.groups()[1]
```